# Hydrate object with a native query using subquery result symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get fully hydrated object in a repository depending a subquery in a native
query (looking for products similar to others in customer order)

SQL query is working as expected

```
$sql = 'SELECT
        (
            SELECT p2.id_produit FROM produit p2
            WHERE p2.id_produit != produit.id_produit
            LIMIT 1
         ) as similar
        FROM item_commande
        INNER JOIN produit ON (produit.id_produit = item_commande.id_produit)
        INNER JOIN produit_to_categorie ON (produit_to_categorie.id_produit = produit.id_produit)
        GROUP BY produit_to_categorie.id_categorie
        LIMIT 6'
;
```

But when i am using doctrine

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('ProductBundle:Product', 'similar');

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
dump($query->getResult());
```

**1st Problem when doing this :**
Products returned are the one of produit and i need those returned by similar

**so i have tried this :**

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('ProductBundle\Entity\Product','p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p','similar','id');
```

It's work but object are not fully hydrated (only id)

Thanks for any help,

Regards